# How to generate well-aligned Equal Signs?

Tags: org-mode

There are many project description files using a quite neat structure like this:

```
Introduction
============

......bla..bla.....


Details
=======

......bla..bla.....
```

**My question is**: Is there any convenient ways to generate automatically the title using such structure as:

```
Title
=====
```

, *where* the number of Equal Sign(=) is well aligned to the that of characters of the title just preceding it.

Comment: Write your file in Org mode and export as text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [documentation](https://joaotavora.github.io/yasnippet/snippet-development.html) for `yasnippet` gives almost exactly this workflow as an example of its "field mirroring" capabilities. That's for *entering* titles; it might be possible to adapt it to edit existing well-structured text too.

For example, with the following snippet, press `C-c u` and start typing. When you're done, press `TAB`.

```
# -*- mode: snippet -*-
# name: underline
# binding : C-c u
# --
${1:}
${1:$(make-string (string-width yas-text) ?\=)}

$0
```

Comment: Thank you @jagrg. It seems unfair that I can't upvote you for such a substantive assist.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following command to underline the line at point.

```lisp
(defun underline ()
  (interactive)
  (let* ((line (string-trim (thing-at-point 'line t)))
         (underline (make-string (string-width line) ?\=))
         (padding (save-excursion
                    (forward-line 0)
                    (when (re-search-forward "[^ ]" (point-at-eol) t)
                      (make-string (1- (current-column)) ?\s)))))
    (unless (string-empty-p underline)    
      (insert (format "\n%s%s\n\n" padding underline)))))
```

Comment: Thanks! The solution just works perfectly as well! Would definitely upvote for it if I have enough SE Reputation.